# Use external Javascript Libraries IN BigQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, requirejs

New to user-defined UDFs, so excuse if this is a dumb question.

Can I use a standard http library to make a request FROM a BigQuery function?

Basically I want to be able to make a function that's available from SQL, that will trigger an external service over http.

I've tried both import and require for the http library in my custom function, but both fail when running the Javascript in BigQuery.

```
'use strict';

function https(){
    let res = '';
    http = require('http');
    http.get('https://google.com'), (resp) => {
      let data = "";
      resp.on('end', () => {
        res = "pinged";
      });
    };

    return res;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not possible

Answer (score 1):

As Elliott Brossard said, this isn't possible.

The solution I wound up with is having a library of UDF Javascript functions, and then having another Javascript library which consumes this same code.  The outer library handles all the web traffic stuff.

Comment: but, still ... it is not possible to do so from within BQ JS UDF!!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant no, it is not possible to do so.